# I would appreciate help converting ints/floats to strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fiveYears;
fiveYears = 5 * 1.5;
    
int sevenYears;
sevenYears = 7 * 1.5;

int tenYears;
tenYears = 10 * 1.5;

int main()
{
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << fiveYears << "millimeters\n";
    
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << sevenYears << "millimeters\n";
    
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << tenYears << "millimeters\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So this is what I have so far. I have only started c++ about a week ago and I am still unsure about how to convert floats and integers into strings. My output should prints the statements with the results of the strings.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You have no std::strings in the code. Note that all of your variables are integer meaning there is no fractional part.

Comment: The program does not compile. Is that your question?

Comment: You can't have arbitrary statements outside a function so `fiveYears = 5 * 1.5;` is invalid. However `int fiveYears = 5 * 1.5;` would be acceptable but you should avoid global variables anyways so move this code inside `int main()`

Comment: Tip: Condense your definitions from `int x; x = ...` into `int x = ...`. Secondly, *learn to use arrays*. Having multiple related variables like this is a mess. You want `std::map<int, int>` so you can insert pairs like 5, 5 * 1.5. Even better: **Write a function to compute these**, as in `int level(const int years)`.

Comment: These don't get converted to strings per-se, they just get rendered as text to `cout`.

Comment: Can you explain how you "started c++ about a week ago"? Are there some similar programs in your C++ textbook that you're trying to emulate, or is this a sample problem? How do the example programs, in the same chapter this excersize is from, do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fiveYears;
int sevenYears;
int tenYears;

int main()
{
    fiveYears = 5 * 1.5;
    sevenYears = 7 * 1.5;
    tenYears = 10 * 1.5;
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << fiveYears << " millimeters\n";
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << sevenYears << " millimeters\n";
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << tenYears << " millimeters\n";
    return 0;
}
```

or this

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fiveYears = 5 * 1.5;
int sevenYears = 7 * 1.5;
int tenYears = 10 * 1.5;

int main()
{
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << fiveYears << " millimeters\n";
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << sevenYears << " millimeters\n";
    cout << "In years the ocean's level will be higher by " << tenYears << " millimeters\n";
    return 0;
}
```

to resolve this issue if you really want to use global variables.

Comment: This isn't resolving the type issue, which really has nothing to do with global variables. In this example results of floating arithmetic will be cast to integers, which doesn't address the OP's issues. Granted, this fixes the compilation issues related to having statements at the global level.

Comment: There are compile errors which this answer fixes however if the OP does not better explain the problem it's all guessing and that is why the two answers are so very different.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)
Converts a numeric value to std::string.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int v1 = 61;
    long v2 = 62L;
    long long v3 = 63LL;
    unsigned int v4 = 64;
    unsigned long v5 = 65UL;
    unsigned long long v6 = 66ULL;
    float v7 = 67.0f;
    double v8 = 68.0;
    long double v9 = 69.0L;

    std::string v1Str = std::to_string(v1);
    std::string v2Str = std::to_string(v2);
    std::string v3Str = std::to_string(v3);
    std::string v4Str = std::to_string(v4);
    std::string v5Str = std::to_string(v5);
    std::string v6Str = std::to_string(v6);
    std::string v7Str = std::to_string(v7);
    std::string v8Str = std::to_string(v8);
    std::string v9Str = std::to_string(v9);

    std::cout << v1Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v2Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v3Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v4Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v5Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v6Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v7Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v8Str << std::endl;
    std::cout << v9Str << std::endl;

    int fiveYears = 5;
    int sevenYears = 7;
    int tenYears = 10;
    float ratio = 1.5;

    std::cout << u8"In " + std::to_string(fiveYears) + u8" years the ocean\'s level will be higher by " + std::to_string(fiveYears * ratio) + u8" millimeters" << std::endl;
    std::cout << u8"In " + std::to_string(sevenYears) + u8" years the ocean\'s level will be higher by " + std::to_string(sevenYears * ratio) + u8" millimeters" << std::endl;
    std::cout << u8"In " + std::to_string(tenYears) + u8" years the ocean\'s level will be higher by " + std::to_string(tenYears * ratio) + u8" millimeters" << std::endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
61
62
63
64
65
66
67.000000
68.000000
69.000000
In 5 years the ocean's level will be higher by 7.5 millimeters
In 7 years the ocean's level will be higher by 10.5 millimeters
In 10 years the ocean's level will be higher by 15 millimeters
```

Check/run this example in https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/IntFloatsToString#main.cpp

Comment: Note; The `L, LL` at the end of the integer constants here are not needed - not harmful either.

Comment: I'm just explaining the use of the function, nothing more. It may or may not be useful.